# How do I dock a resizable ExtJS Ext.Panel within another resizable docked panel

Tags: flexbox, panel, dock, extjs6-modern

I have a Modern ExtJS Ext.Panel docked left with resizable set with edge 'east'.
IN this left panel, I want

- Flex upper panel
- docked bottom panel with edge 'north' within the docked left panel.

The "flex" upper left panel does not flex.  See [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3acl&view/editor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turned out that the docked left panel needed a layout: 'vbox'.